# JNA toArray() resets structure fields?

Tags: java, arrays, structure, jna

Consider the following JNA structure:

```java
public class VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo extends VulkanStructure {
    public VkStructureType sType = VkStructureType.VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
    public Pointer pNext;
    public int flags;
    public int queueFamilyIndex;
    public int queueCount;
    public Pointer pQueuePriorities;
}
```

The `sType` field is a constant value used by the native layer to identify the type of structure. This works fine for a **single** instance of this class created using `new`.

However if we allocate an *array* of this structure using `toArray()` the `sType` is reset to the default value **after** the constructor has been invoked for each array element. i.e. it clears the field!

Alternatives that didn't work:

- Setting the field explicitly in the constructor has no effect (it still gets reset).
- Ditto making the field `final`.
- Doesn't seem to matter whether we try the default constructor or one with a JNA `Pointer` argument.

The only thing that seems to work is to turn off auto-read for the structure:

```java
public class VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo extends VulkanStructure {
    ...
    public VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo() {
        setAutoRead(false);
    }
}
```

(Note that this structure is **only** used to write to the native layer, not read anything back).

This works but what is it actually doing?  Why is JNA resetting the structure to the native values when there aren't any yet?  Is there a way to switch off the auto-read for this field globally?

This is not a big deal for a single structure, but in this project there are several hundred that were code generated from the native layer, most of which (but not all) with the `sType` pre-populated as the above example.  Clearly pre-populating the field was not was the way to go, but what is the alternative?  Will every structure need to be re-generated with the above fiddle?

EDIT: Another related question that comes to mind after brooding on this - what about array types in a structure?  Are they reset to `null` by the auto-read thingy?  The code-generated structures initialise any arrays to size the structure, e.g. `public float[] colour = new float[4];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track pointing out that the auto-`read()` is part of the problem here.  When you invoke `toArray()` you are (usually) changing the memory backing for the array to a new native memory allocation (the auto-allocation zeroes out the memory).  So all those 0's are loaded into your array.

The internal Structure `toArray()` keeps the values for the first element for your convenience, but does nothing for the remainder, which are instantiated using `newInstance()` inside the loop.  Here are the two lines causing your problem:

```java
array[i] = newInstance(getClass(), memory.share(i*size, size));
array[i].conditionalAutoRead();
```

My recommendation would be for you to override `toArray()` in your own `VulkanStructure` structure that the others inherit from.  You could copy over the existing code and modify it as you see fit (e.g., remove the autoRead).

Or you could overload a `toArray()` that gets passed a collection of Structures and copies over the backing memory from the old collection before reading it to the new one.  Alternately, if the original memory backing is large enough when `toArray()` is called, the memory isn't cleared.  So you could allocate your own large enough memory, use `useMemory()` on the first element to change its backing, and copy over the backing memory bytes; and they would be auto-read into the new array version.

Comment: Hello again, thanks for the response, you confirmed my understanding of what the problem was and how to get around it.  Think I will use the approach of over-riding the auto-read behaviour in the affected structures (means re-code-generating the code but them's the breaks!)

Comment: I think there's room for an elegant "copy the native memory from your collection" per earlier questions. Step 1: allocate new big enough memory block. Step 2: iterate collection, using `setMemory()` at the correct offset and writing.  Step 3: use `toArray()` on element `[0]`.  Step 4: ???? Step 5: Profit!